# Can I link Power App to a server containing sensitive data without loading it on the cloud?

Tags: powerapps, dataverse, power-platform

I am an intern in a company that deals with very sensitive data.

I am in charge for setting up a database for this data on the on-premise servers of the company, and I need to set up an application that allows users to fill in forms that will later add to the database.

My question is as follows : is there any way at all I could use Power Apps for this project ? Meaning, can I use the Power Platform directly on my servers rather than first bringing it on the cloud (through Dataverse I suppose) and then apply whatever operation I like, without it spending time on Microsoft's cloud ?

I have trouble finding a definitive answer for this question, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: bruh how this is a no code platform